# Require that the same thing be done at the beginning of every override of abstract method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class with an abstract method that I want subclasses to override. I need to ensure that every override of this method has the same specific line of code at the start, i.e. like this:

```
abstract void method();
```

and later

```
@Override
void method() {
    // mandatory line of code

    // do stuff here
}
```

I don't like this naive approach, since it isn't a hard requirement, i.e. an override can theoretically be made without that line. I was also thinking of doing this:

```
public void wrapper() {
    // mandatory line of code goes here

    method();
}

abstract void method();
```

I also don't like this, since I will only want to call `wrapper()` from the outside, and not `method()`, so it would make sense for `method` to be private, and yet it is public by default (since it is abstract). Is there a neater way? Or should I just make it a precondition that you must include the mandatory line of code, otherwise you get undefined behaviour?

Comment: Instead of a mandatory LoC, I'd suggest a mandatory call to `super.method`

Comment: @AyushGupta yeah, I think that's a better idea actually

Comment: You're supposed to take the second approach. If you'd like you can make method protected.